# Text File Wrong Encoding issue

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a text file that contains a strange encoded characters, the original characters of the file was Arabic characters.

As a sample: the file contains this string `ÝíæáÇ ãÍÝæÑ` which equivalent to `فيولا محفور`

other some examples here:

```
ÈÇÑíÜÜÜÜÜÒ = باريـــــز
ÏíäÇ ÔÇÌ = دينا شاج
ßíÑãÇäì ãÍÝæÑ = كيرمانى محفور
ÇäÌì ÈÇáÝæã ãßãáÇÊ = انجى بالفوم مكملات
ÓÈÔíÇá ÑæíÇá 35 ãáã = سبشيال رويال 35 ملم
```

Is there is any way to revert back the file content to its original Arabic characters?

Note: I am using C# programming language.

Comment: Maybe "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)" by Joel Spolsky can help?

Comment: +1 for referencing Joel! That article is something I burned into my brain when I read it back in the ole days :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Arabic encodings, but I assume that your text file is encoded using a [Windows-1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256) code page.

So you need to specify this codepage when reading the file:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(pathToFile, Encoding.GetEncoding(1256));
```